# Upgrading to React 18 - can no longer use strings as ReactText

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a project from React 17 to React 18 and I'm running into an issue where previously, I was able to render `strings` as `Cells` for my column definitions. E.g.

```
{
    Header: t("common.from").toString(),
    accessor: (rentalOrder) => WDate.toSortString(rentalOrder.from),
    Cell: ({ row }: CellProps<SearchResultRentalOrder>) => WDate.toShortString(row.original.from)
}
```

This is for `react-table 7` by the way. In React 17 this was allowed, yet in React 18 I'm getting an error:

```
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'
```

When I look at the typings for `Cell`, I see the following definition:

```
export type Renderer<Props> = ComponentType<Props> | ReactElement | ReactText | ReactFragment;
```

Where `ReactText` has the following definition:

```
type ReactText = string | number;
```

So I'd expect that a string is still allowed.
I know I can wrap my cell in an empty fragment or a `span`, but feels like the wrong solution. Are there any other options?

Comment: This is a Typscript error, and doing some testing using Typescript playground, on pretty much any version of Typescript assigning a string to `Renderer` is fine.  Are you able to knock up a snippet showing this error.